# RHEL/CentOS 7 - Which MPM should I use for multiple vhosts?

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, rhel7

I'm working on a RHEL7 environment with Apache 2.4.6 and I need to set up several vhosts for several users (let's say one vhost each UID).

In the last two days I've read almost everything related to MPMs and vhosts configuration.
A couple of questions have crossed my mind though:

1. is mpm-itk the only MPM capable of handling multiple UID/GIDs e to set options in a per-vhost perspective?
2. since it's not native on RHEL based distros, is it possible to achieve the same thing without installing mpm-itk?

   - If yes: how?
   - if no: is it possible/safe to install mpm-itk on RHEL 7?

Don't know if it is a silly question. I hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mpm-itk Apache module is available in the `httpd-itk` package in EPEL. I've never heard of anything else that solves the same problem in any similar manner.

Comment: Thanks, I went further while waiting for a reply here and I managed to install httpd-itk directly from yum.